# scaledValueForValue: called on a font that doesn't have a text style set

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I am currently using the Xcode 6 pre release (not beta) and the simulator on OS X 10.10 Yosemite beta 7. I am trying to build a project developed in xcode 6, but the app crashes whenever I open a certain view controller. This view controller literally has no code in it (it is an empty, static, table view controller that has a couple of default cells and labels).

The error given is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:  
'scaledValueForValue: called on a font that doesn't have a text style set'
```

And right before I am given this assertion failure:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICTFont _scaledValueForValue:],         
/SourceCache/UIFoundation_Sim/UIFoundation-371/UIFoundation/iOS/UIFont.m:496
```

I seriously have no idea what is going on, I tried setting breakpoints in the VC but the error happens after the viewDidLoad method is called (and thus after all my code is executed).

Any Ideas? The fonts for everything in my project is 'Baskerville' and I have tried changing that but it does not affect the crash.

Oh, and it works fine if I use Xcode 5.

*Update 9/24*: So I am still unable to figure this out. I tried using the fontWithDescriptor method, but it still crashes. The funny thing is, I have plenty of pages that use custom fonts and most of them work fine, but there are two VCs that crash immediately when I go to them... one of them doesn't even have any custom fonts. I really appreciate all of your feedback, but does anyone have any other ideas/fixes? I am using the official release of Xcode and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm not even setting fonts in my app. Only 1 pod. Did you find a way to fix it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in iOS 8.1.

Instead of spending time building a custom header/footer view, I just not apply the custom font to devices running iOS 8.0. Most people will probably have updated to iOS 8.1 anyway.

I use the following code for this:

```
NSOperatingSystemVersion iOS_8_1 = (NSOperatingSystemVersion){8, 1, 0};

if (![[NSProcessInfo processInfo] respondsToSelector:@selector(isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:)]
    || [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:iOS_8_1]) {
    header.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Medium" size:header.textLabel.font.pointSize];
}
```

The first statement is true if the device is running an iOS version lower than 8 (since `isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:` was introduced in iOS 8.0). The second statement is true if the device if running iOS 8.1 or later. With both statements we thus only exclude devices running iOS 8.0.

Comment: What a relief! I'm glad I don't have to worry about this pesky bug anymore. :)

Answer (score 4):

Okay I finally figured it out.

This occurs when grouped table views have section headers and possibly footers. As a temporary workaround I am just removing the headers/footers from the grouped tableviews, but if you really need the font you can create a custom header view by overriding the "viewForHeaderInSection", and setting the font on your custom view's label.

Still, this is definitely a bug in iOS 8 and hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Comment: In my case it crashed when i apply custom font to UITableViewHeaderFooterView.detailLabel. When i use standart Font with custom size it work well.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at: http://openradar.io/17623734

Unfortunately at this early stages of xCode 6 I can only offer a workaround for the crash.

Replace this line:

```
[header.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17]];
```

for this:

```
header.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:[UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFontAttributes:@{@"NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute" : UIFontTextStyleBody,
                                                                                                        @"NSFontNameAttribute" : @"HelveticaNeue-Italic"}] size:17.0];
```

Comment: I have the same issue and tried to use the fontWithDescriptor call. The crash problem is solved but the font is not set to my specified font name. Any other trick I've missed?

Comment: I encountered the same. Follow the suggestion, it fixed the crash but the font is not set to specified.

Comment: Sorry guys, but I was unable to set a custom font myself. I could only set italic:

Comment: `UIFontDescriptor *style = [UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
UIFontDescriptor *italic = [style fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic];`

Comment: Same issue here. Crash eliminated, custom font not set. I've seen this issue on http://openradar.io/17623734 but I can't find anything about it in http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well and it still didn't work. Did it work for you?

Comment: This fixed the crash, but the font did not change so I think it just doesn't set the font.

Comment: Does not work, it fixes the crash but custom font not set. See my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239296/custom-fonts-in-ios-8-not-showing

Comment: The expectation is that the object set for the key "NSFontNameAttribute" is a UIFont object, not the name.

Answer (score 3):

Like everyone here, applying the fix in other answers caused the font setting to be ignored. What I ended up doing was having my own UITableViewHeaderFooterView (Where it seems the cause for the crash is coming from) subclasses that had a label that I added myself. I then used this label instead of the textLabel property inherited from UITableViewHeaderFooterView, set up the auto layout constraints, set the font, and all was right once again (though not what I would consider ideal). I'll add again that this seems to be iOS 8 unique.

Comment: How did you go about maintaining the various different spacing that seem to be applied to these depending on whether a footer is the bottom in the tableview, or when the header comes directly after a section with a footer? Perhaps these are only issues with footers, are you using any footers?

Comment: Awesome! Solved the issue for my headers.

Comment: Can you show the code you used to subclass `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and add a label to it?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found workaround. It is simple, you just need to construct font in other direction :)

```
// 1. Grab your custom font
CGFloat size = 17.0f;
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Brandon Grotesque" size:size];

// 2. Get descriptor for your font and create new descriptor with
UIFontDescriptorTextStyleAttribute and UIFontDescriptorSizeAttribute attributes from it.

UIFontDescriptor *des = [[font fontDescriptor] fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes:@{
   UIFontDescriptorTextStyleAttribute: UIFontTextStyleBody, // You can tune this style based on usage
   UIFontDescriptorSizeAttribute: @(size)
}];

// 3. Get your font
UIFont *finalFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:des size:0.0]
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, stops the crash but doesn't use the custom font

Comment: Unfortunately, this stops the crash from happening but does not change the font, only the font size.

Comment: Does not work for me on iOS 8. Stops the crash but custom font not set. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239296/custom-fonts-in-ios-8-not-showing

Answer (score 1):

This problem is still present in iOS 8.0.2 but seems to be fixed in 8.1.

My workaround was to set the custom font only if iOS is greater than 8.0.2:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)

...

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(@"8.0.2")) {
    [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This only happens for me when using either a UITableView or UITableViewController where `initWithStyle:` method call is set to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`. Changing the style to `UITableViewStylePlain` resolved the issues.

Comment: I'd love to know who down voted this and why. This solution worked for what was clearly a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here: set a custom font for UITableViewHeaderFooterView in my app init, get this crash when showing a grouped UITableView.

What works for me is to delay customisation until the view controller is being created, i.e. do whatever you would have done at app init in the view controller's init. Irritating, but works for me.

```
- (id) init
{
  ...

  if (self = [super init])
  {
    // customise table view headers
    UILabel *headerLabel =
      [UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil];

    headerLabel.font =
      [UIFont fontWithName: @"AvenirNext-Medium" size: 15];

    ...
  }
}
```