# Assertion Failure in -[UICTFont _scaledValueForValue:];

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uifont

In the process of upgrading my app to iOS 8, I'm running into a strange issue that only seems to happen on iOS 8. When ever I set the title text attributes of a UITableViewHeaderFooterView using the appearance API, I get this assertion failure:

> *** Assertion failure in `-[UICTFont _scaledValueForValue:]`, /SourceCache/UIFoundation_Sim/UIFoundation-371/UIFoundation/iOS/UIFont.m:496

The code I am using to set the attributes is this:

`[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17]];`

As you can see it's very simple, nothing fancy.

Here is the relevant part of the stack trace I'm getting:

> ```
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 
> 'scaledValueForValue: called on a font that doesn't have a text style set'
> *** First throw call stack:
> (
>   0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001105ef3f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
>   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110288bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
>   2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001105ef25a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
>   3   Foundation                          0x000000010e75c28f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
>   4   UIFoundation                        0x0000000113055b5b -[UIFont _scaledValueForValue:] + 241
>   5   UIKit                               0x000000010f67d0d6 -[UITableViewHeaderFooterView _labelFrame] + 1517
>   6   UIKit                               0x000000010f67f4ed -[UITableViewHeaderFooterView layoutSubviews] + 220
>   7   UIKit                               0x000000010f05d199 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
>   8   QuartzCore                          0x000000010ee6ff98 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
> ```

There was a [radar created](http://openradar.io/17623734) for this issue but it hasn't had any response since beta 3. I'm currently using Xcode 6.0.1 using the latest public release of iOS 8. If anyone knows what's going on, any insight is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [scaledValueForValue: called on a font that doesn't have a text style set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773661/scaledvalueforvalue-called-on-a-font-that-doesnt-have-a-text-style-set)